# Using JSTL enable/disable button based on text entry in text area

Tags: jsp, jstl, jstl-functions

I am new to JSTL, I know it's quite straight forward in JavaScript/jQuery but wanted to know how I will be able to achieve the result using JSTL on a JSP page.

Actually I have a form with a text area in it with a Confirm and Cancel buttons underneath. I want to keep the "Confirm" button disabled as long as their is no entry in the TextArea. What I have right now is something like this,

```
<h3>Enter details of your approval for this proposal.</h3>
<textarea name="approval-reason" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea><br/>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='Controller?action=ProposalDetails&proposalNo=${proposalNumber}'" />
```

Any help with a highly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: JSTL works on server side. So you should not (& have no reason to) use JSTL.

Comment: I'm guessing, then a simply JavaScript or jQuery enable/disable button would be the only way forward